# Filter collapse issue on small screens

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using Backpack for Laravel v4.1.10.

After the upgrade from v.4.0 the filter collapse button in small screens stopped working.
On button click my console error is:

`TypeError: can't convert n to string`

on the following line of bundle.js (line 9920 expanded):

`if (!i && o.toggle && /show|hide/.test(n) && (o.toggle = !1), i || (i = new t(this, o), r.data('bs.collapse', i)), 'string' == typeof n)`

Other info: php v7.3.9, Laravel v.7.16.1

Apparently it is not a framework bug as it is not existent in the live demo of backpack.

Any feedback to troubleshoot the issue is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing the bundle.js file with the one provided in the official repository of backpack. Maybe it had not been updated at the version upgrade although I cannot fathom a reason for that.

Comment: Better late than never, I hope - I believe the reason for that is that Backpack does not re-publish the assets, when you do a `composer update`. You can get the newest CSS&JS assets pretty easily, but it's manual. We've recently written an article of how you can automate that (and why) - https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tips-and-tricks/once-in-a-while-re-publish-backpack-s-css-and-js-assets

Comment: Indeed, I have realised this since then. Thank you for your feedback, it will helps others having similar issues.